# GCC preprocessor not working? Compile time of large files with or without comments

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I suspect the gcc preprocessor is not working correctly because there is an inexplicable correlation of compiling time with or without comments and with or without optimization.

I have a huge Matlab generated c-file (about 70.000 lines).

I noticed when I compile it with optimization level -O3 it takes > 30 minutes to compile. When switching optimization off (-O0) it just takes 4 minutes. That was exactly what I would expect because optimization may be complex on large files.

But, if I generate that same file in Matlab without comments (or delete them with an editor) it compiles in 16 minutes with, and in 2 minutes without optimization.

Where does the factor 2 come from? I would expect that optimization is done after preprocessing and preprocessing should remove any comments. That would result in a fix time difference independent from o-level. I'm confused.

I tried to display the preprocessed output (with gcc option -E) and there are no comments. If I additionally use option -C there are comments.

If I delete empty lines and consecutive spaces it affects the compile time too. Compile time seems to be linear file size depending...

Comment: You're assuming that the compiler implements each phase independently.

Comment: Basic benchmarking questions. Did you run both multiple times? It's possible you're just benchmarking disk caching. Did you ***completely*** clean the source tree between runs? Not `make clean`, that doesn't always get everything, start with a fresh source tree. It's possible you have compilation units still cached. Are you using something like `ccache`?

Comment: And ensure your machine isn't doing anything else while you compile, especially something disk intensive.

Comment: Can you upload your source somewhere for an independent verification?

Comment: Modern C compilers don't implement preprocessing quite as separately as they used to, but you're right that comments are stripped very early in the overall process ("translation phase 3", in C standardese) and that their presence or absence in the input _shouldn't_ cause a factor of 2
 difference in compilation time.

Comment: In addition to the _basic benchmarking_ comment, it might be useful to also build with clang, or with another version of gcc. It's always good to have some points of comparison for unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions so far.

I'm using Windows 10 with eclipse and a GCC fork from version 4.8.5.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 with eclipse and a GCC fork from version 4.8.5.

@Schwern: Compilation time is reproducible and does not depend on other activities (as only one core is busy with this). Before every run I change a char in the large source, press save and then build. I pay attention that only this one file is being compiled.

Sorry! I'm not allowed to share that code.

A colleague compiled the file on a Linux machine (similar hardware) in less than 5 minutes. 

My assumption is that is has something to do with a crappy Windows memory managing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason:

Someone (at an early stage of the project) turned on the option "-Wa,-amhls" that causes the assembler to generate a > 500.000 lines long combined .lst file from .S and .C input files.

Building that file on a Windows machine takes over 30 Minutes. (Linux is much faster!)

Also that's the reason why build time depends on optimizing and comments turned on/off. Both have influence to the length of that .lst file.

With that option turned off my project builds in  less than 3 minutes.